# How to extract different datatype data from an ASCII array using templates

Tags: c++11, templates

I'm trying to extract different datatype data from an ASCII array using templates where each datatype data is separated by a delimiter(':' in this case) also each datatype data can be preceded and succeeded by whitespaces which needs to removed. But I'm getting template instantiation error. Can somebody enlighten me how to accomplish this task. This is my sample code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>


class Extract {
public:
    inline Extract() {
        length = 0;
        std::memset(recvBuff, '\0', sizeof(recvBuff));
    }

    inline ~Extract() {
    }

    int length;
    unsigned char recvBuff[1024];

    template<typename T>
    void extractData(short& start, short& end, T& val, char delimiter, short dataType) {
        while(end <= length) {
            if(recvBuff[end] == delimiter)
                break;

            end++;
        }

        if(end >= length)
            return;

        std::string token(recvBuff[start + 1], end - start - 1);
        std::string trimmedToken;

        std::string::size_type first = token.find_first_not_of(" \n\r\t\f\v");
        std::string::size_type last = token.find_last_not_of(" \n\r\t\f\v");

        if((first == std::string::npos) || (last == std::string::npos))
            return;
        else
            trimmedToken.assign(token, first, (last - first + 1));

        if(dataType == 1) { //char
            if(trimmedToken.size() == 1)
                val = trimmedToken.at(0);
        }
        else if(dataType == 2) { //int
            if(trimmedToken.size() > 0)
                val = std::stoi(trimmedToken);
        }
        else if(dataType == 3) { //float
            if(trimmedToken.size() > 0)
                val = std::stod(trimmedToken);
        }
        else if(dataType == 4) { //std::string
            val.assign(trimmedToken);
        }
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
     //"contains mixed ascii data of char, int, float separated by :" for example
     //" CMD : 123 : 3453.45646 : REP : T : 2424 : 3424 : 803424.2312 "
    char buff[1024];

    Extract objExtract;
    objExtract.length = 60; // some dummy value for time being
    std::memcpy(objExtract.recvBuff, buff, objExtract.length);

    short start = 0;
    short end = 1;

    std::string data1;
    objExtract.extractData(start, end, data1, ':', 4);

    int data2;
    objExtract.extractData(start, end, data2, ':', 2);

    double data3;
    objExtract.extractData(start, end, data3, ':', 3);

    std::string data4;
    objExtract.extractData(start, end, data4, ':', 4);

    char data5;
    objExtract.extractData(start, end, data5, ':', 1);

    int data6;
    objExtract.extractData(start, end, data6, ':', 2);

    int data7;
    objExtract.extractData(start, end, data7, ':', 2);

    double data8;
    objExtract.extractData(start, end, data8, ':', 3);

    std::cout << data1 << "\t" << data2 << std::endl;

    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `extractData` for example for `data2` the code

```
else if(dataType == 4) { //std::string
            val.assign(trimmedToken);
        }
```

is compiled. Type of `val` is `int&`. You got error because `int` doesn't have `assign` method.

With C++17 you can use `if constexpr (condition) { block }`, where `condition` is known at compile-time, if it is true, `{block}` will be compiled.

You can change signature of function to be:

```
template<typename T>
void extractData(short& start, short& end, T& val, char delimiter) {
```

and *if* block can be rewritten:

```
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T,char>) { //char
        if(trimmedToken.size() == 1)
            val = trimmedToken.at(0);
    }
    else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T,int>) { //int
        if(trimmedToken.size() > 0)
            val = std::stoi(trimmedToken);
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T,float>) { //float
        if(trimmedToken.size() == 1)
            val = std::stod(trimmedToken);
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T,std::string>) { //std::string
        val.assign(trimmedToken);
    }
```

you don't need to pass `dataType`, because it can be deduced from third parameter.

---

Under C++11 you can declare function template which does conversion, and you have to provide specialization for all types you want to support:

```
template<class T>
void convert(std::string, T&);

template<>
void convert<char>(std::string trimmedToken, char& val) {
    if(trimmedToken.size() > 0)
        val = std::stoi(trimmedToken);
}

template<>
void convert<int>(std::string trimmedToken, int& val) {
    if(trimmedToken.size() > 0)
        val = std::stoi(trimmedToken);
}

template<>
void convert<float>(std::string trimmedToken, float& val) {
    if(trimmedToken.size() == 1)
       val = std::stod(trimmedToken);
}

template<>
void convert<std::string>(std::string trimmedToken, std::string& val) {
    val.assign(trimmedToken);
}
```

then remove *if* block and replace it by one line:

```
    convert(trimmedToken,val);
```

when you call `convert` with `val` which is not supported by specializations, you will get linker's error. So you need to add version for `double`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I want to know whether this can be accomplished using C++11 standard because my compiler doesn't support C++17 standard

Comment: @Harry Edited for C++11.